# Turn Kotlin suspend function into Callback-based function

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Image, you have a Kotlin suspend function

`suspend fun foo(): String { return "" }`

I need to make it callback-based instead of suspend, i.e.

```
interface Cancellable {
    fun cancel()
}

internal class CancellableImpl : Cancellable {
    var cancellationCallback: (() -> Unit)? = null

    override fun cancel() {
        cancellationCallback?.invoke()
    }
}

fun foo(callback: (String) -> Unit): Cancellable
```

Would GlobalScope approach work? I.e.

```
fun foo(callback: (String) -> Unit): Cancellable {
        val task = CancellableImpl()

        val job = GlobalScope.launch {
            val fooResult = foo()
            callback(fooResult)
        }

        task.cancellationCallback = {
            job.cancel()
        }
        return task
}
```

Which drawbacks it has?

Answer (score 1):

Whether GlobalScope is appropriate depends on your use case. If you use GlobalScope, it is up to the caller to manually cancel the task when it is no longer needed so it doesn’t hang onto resources and references longer than necessary.

Your current solution is not thread-safe and fires its callbacks on arbitrary threads from Dispatchers.Default. If you’re on Android, you may want to fire those callbacks on the Looper that the caller used to call your function.

Do you really need callbacks specifically? I would use the following so you don’t have to worry about implementing thread safety yourself.

```
GlobalScope.async { foo() }.asCompletableFuture()
```

Comment: > If you use GlobalScope, it is up to the caller to manually cancel the task when it is no longer needed so it doesn’t hang onto resources and references longer than necessary.

Do you mean Cancellable interface here? Or there's other ways to cancel task?

```
interface Cancellable {
    fun cancel()
}
```

Comment: Yes, if you’re using your own interface like that. You need to call `cancel()` when the resources are no longer needed. Kind of obvious, but you wouldn’t have to if using `viewModelScope` or `lifecycleScope`.